# How to replace . character within code with regex?

Tags: regex

I already read outer StackOverflow posts and tried the online regex websites.

I want to replace a dot with an underscore:

aab.ccc --> aab_ccc

but in the Matlab code are calculations:

```
cost11 =aab.ccc*(v1.^3.*t11  + 1.5*v1.*a1.*t11.^2+ a1.^3.*t11./4/4) + aab.ccc.*t11;
```

The dots .^ .* ./ should not be replaced.  My regex looks like this: `\.(?!(\^|\*|\/)$)`, but it still selects all dots. I also use this regex tool: https://regex101.com/r/rMbYHz/306

What is missing in the regex?

Comment: Do you mean like `\.(?![\^*\/\d])` https://regex101.com/r/qvzkA6/1 also excluding the digits?

Comment: yes also excluding digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, you could use:

```
\.(?![*\/\d^])
```

In parts:

- `\.` Match a dot
- `(?!` Negative lookahead

  - `[*\/\d^]` Match either `*` `/` a digit or `^`
- `)` Close lookahead.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GpQfhI/1)

Note that for the pattern `(\^|\*|\/)$` you can shorten the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) using the `|` to a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) without the pipe. Using `$` asserts the end of the string, which can be omitted from the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the $

```
\.(?![\^|\*|\/])
```

https://regex101.com/r/Qwbcoc/1

Comment: but now it also replaces the dot at the digits. I think that better is to add use this one: \.(?!(\^|\*|\/|[0-9]))

Comment: Well you didn't say that in your question @j35t3r haha, but it seems the fourth bird has thought of that too! Use his answer :)